# how can I make a checkbox update 2 table fields at once in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two boolean fields in a table in my database.

both are defaulted to FALSE

This is what I have in my view

```
<%= label_tag(:post_draft, "Draft?") %>
<div class="ItemCheckboxAlign"><%= f.check_box :draft %></div>
```

As you can see, I have one of them working correctly. Is it possible to associate the other boolean field so if checked, the value changes to TRUE as well?
I want to keep these two boolean field values completely separate from each other except I'm trying to update both with this one checkbox.

My schema:

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.boolean  "draft",          :default => false
    t.boolean  "sendreminder",          :default => false
  end
```

I'm trying to get the bottom two boolean fields changed to TRUE if the checkmark is checked when a user posts. I already have the "draft" working, but just trying to the other one to change as well at once.

After some discussion below, I am trying to apply the `update_attribute(sendreminder, true)` method. How can I include this in my model to make sendreminder=true only if draft=true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the controller, you can do something like:

```
my_model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
my_model.assign_attributes(params[:my_model])
my_model.sendreminder = my_model.draft
if my_model.save
  bla bla bla
else
  bla bla bla
end
```

just make sure to replace MyModel with the model you are using, and the **bla bla bla** is pseudo code :)

---

If you want that to work the same for each time you save the model, you can use a before filter on your mode.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord:Base
  before_save :associate_draft

  def associate_draft
    self.sendreminder = self.draft unless self.sendreminder == true
  end
end
```

and then every time you save or update the model, that filter will be executed and the value of post_draft will be always the same value than draft.

Comment: so there's no way to just associate the second field in this code `<%= f.check_box :draft %>`? I have updated the original post with the schema do further clarify what I was asking

Comment: in your updated code, shouldn't I be setting "sendreminder" value to be the same as "draft" in `:associate_draft`?

Comment: I forgot to mention - I need to set the value of "draft" back into FALSE for some of the posts (after a manual review by me while keeping "sendreminder" to be true) but using `before_save :associate_draft` prevents me from doing that. How can I fix this?

Comment: If that's the case, forgot about the **before_save** and update the value on the controller, so later you can set the values of both **draft** and **sendreminder** in any way you want. If you want to save the model without invoking the **before_save** filter, you can use the method **update_attribute**: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute

Comment: To clarify, the "draft" value is temporary while the "sendreminder" value is permanent. I have a method defined in my Post Controller that makes the "draft" value change back into false, but after adding `before_save`, I'm unable to do this now

Comment: I'm reading through your link, but is there a possibility to simply make the **sendreminder** always turn into True if **draft** is True, but make this one way? Meaning, once **sendreminder** has been set to True, it will not be reverted back or get in the way of anything while **draft** can be reverted by me?

Comment: so you can check that the update is only performed when the sendreminder attribute is true, that should do the job

Comment: I had to make a slight modification to the code to get it to work, but thanks for leading me in the right direction. Accepting answer now

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a `before_save` callback to your model and check whether you need to update other fields or not, based on the new state of the model instance.

Comment: I'm trying to use this `before_save` callback in my model and it makes the two table fields equal so that works. However it causes one problem. I need to update one of the fields called "draft" back into FALSE after a manual review by me while keeping the second field called "sendreminder" as TRUE permanently, but this `before_save` prevents any of that from happening. When I try to make the "draft" value back into false, nothing happens. Do you know if this can be fixed?